# Kali Linux scale problem when installing on virtual box

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I have an issue with my screen size as it is way to small as can be seen in the appended image. I have already installed guest additions and tried out different resolutions but that didn't change anything. Can anyone help me to get the correct size?
[image: Image of desktop]

Comment: Can you provide these details? The version of VirtualBox you are using The host and guest OSes Whether you have enabled VT-x/AMD-V (applicable to all hosts running 6.1 and above) and disabled HyperV (applicable to Windows 10 Hosts) Whether you have installed Guest Additions and/or Host Extensions (this solves 90% of the problems we see)

Comment: @SabyasachiRout I'm running virtual box on macOS and have installed guest additions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`tried out different resolutions` You didn't mention that what you tried (You tried in Virtual Box or Kali). If you tried by changing virtual box resolution than try to change resolution in Kali. Change resolution in Virtual Box also. Virtual box's resolution and Kali's resolution should be matched with your laptop screen size. Otherwise you will face issue with your screen resolution that's what you are facing now. Nonetheless, if you are facing the issue than comment below I will provide a YT video cause, when I was using Virtual Box. I noticed that Virtual Box always can't detect your screen size. That moment you have to try something else.

Comment: yes, I have tried to change the resolution in Kali as well as in Virtual box, but neither worked